# How to Move heroku/master forward to HEAD in Git

Tags: git, heroku

My git log looks like this:

```
* c6d7ed2 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add edit category feature & resize Jumbotron
* 7cbd014 (heroku/master) Update all views with categories`enter code here`
```

I would like move heroku/master forward to the same line as HEAD -> origin/master.  How is this best done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the latest `origin/master` changes to `heroku/master`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git push heroku master
```